# I want to pass my data into database with the select radio button

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I have 4 radio buttons(news,birthday,anniversary,obituary) when i select anyone from it the data should be passed on that particular selected radio button but it does not pass with the selected particular radio button it passes only in news not other one.

Here is my angular code.

```
<div class="box1">
                        <input type="radio" name="category" value="news" data-category="news"> News
                        <input type="radio" name="category" value="obituary" data-category="obituary"> Obituary
                        <input type="radio" name="category" value="birthday" data-category="birthday"> Birthday
                        <input type="radio" name="category" value="anniversary" data-category="anniversary"> Anniversary
                      </div>
```

**my ts file**

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApiserviceService } from '../apiservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-newsform',
  templateUrl: './newsform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./newsform.component.css']
})
export class NewsformComponent implements OnInit {
  newsRadioChecked = true;
obituaryRadioChecked = false;
birthdayRadioChecked = false;
anniversaryRadioChecked = false;
onCategoryChange(event: Event) {
  const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const category = target.dataset['category'];
  switch (category) {
    case 'news':
      this.newsRadioChecked = true;
      this.obituaryRadioChecked = false;
      this.birthdayRadioChecked = false;
      this.anniversaryRadioChecked = false;
      break;
    case 'obituary':
      this.newsRadioChecked = false;
      this.obituaryRadioChecked = true;
      this.birthdayRadioChecked = false;
      this.anniversaryRadioChecked = false;
      break;
    case 'birthday':
      this.newsRadioChecked = false;
      this.obituaryRadioChecked = false;
      this.birthdayRadioChecked = true;
      this.anniversaryRadioChecked = false;
      break;
    case 'anniversary':
      this.newsRadioChecked = false;
      this.obituaryRadioChecked = false;
      this.birthdayRadioChecked = false;
      this.anniversaryRadioChecked = true;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}



  errmsg: any;
  selectedFile!: File;
  readData: any;
  constructor(private service:ApiserviceService){}
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  newsForm = new FormGroup({
    headline: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    news: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    path: new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
    currentdate: new FormControl(this.getCurrentDate()),
    expirydate: new FormControl(this.validateExpiryDate()),
  });
  successmsg: any;  
  getCurrentDate(): string {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate());
    const year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    const month = ('0' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    const day = ('0' + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}
  validateExpiryDate(): string{
    const currentdate = new Date();
    const expirydate = new Date(currentdate.getTime());
    expirydate.setDate(currentdate.getDate() + 15);
    if (expirydate <= currentdate) {
      expirydate.setDate(currentdate.getDate() + 15);
    }
    const year = expirydate.getFullYear();
    const month = ('0' + (expirydate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    const day = ('0' + expirydate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  }
  getMinDate(): string {
    const currentdate = new Date();
    currentdate.setDate(currentdate.getDate() + 15);
    const year = currentdate.getFullYear();
    const month = ('0' + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    const day = ('0' + currentdate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  }
  onfileSelected(event: any) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  }

  
  Submit() {
    if (this.newsForm.valid) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      const headline = this.newsForm.get('headline')?.value ?? '';
      const news = this.newsForm.get('news')?.value ?? '';
      const currentdate = this.newsForm.get('currentdate')?.value ?? '';
      const expirydate = this.newsForm.get('expirydate')?.value ?? '';
      const id = this.newsForm.get('id')?.value ?? '';
      
  
      if (headline || news || currentdate || expirydate || this.selectedFile) {
        formData.append('headline', headline);
        formData.append('news', news);
        formData.append('currentdate', currentdate);
        formData.append('expirydate', expirydate);
        formData.append('id', id);
        formData.append('path', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name); // don't include id in the filename here
      }
      console.log(formData)
     
      if (this.newsRadioChecked) {
        this.service.NewsformData(formData).subscribe(
          (res) => {
            console.log(res);
            this.newsForm.reset();
            this.successmsg = res.message;
            const insertedId = res.id; // get the id from the server response
            // use the id to set the filename of the selected file
            this.selectedFile = new File(
              [this.selectedFile],
              `${insertedId}.${this.selectedFile.name.split('.').pop()}`,
              { type: this.selectedFile.type }
            );
          },
          (err) => {
            console.error(err);
            this.errmsg = 'Error uploading file';
          }
        );
      } else if (this.obituaryRadioChecked) {
        this.service.ObituaryformData(formData).subscribe(
          (res) => {
            console.log(res);
            this.newsForm.reset();
            this.successmsg = res.message;
            const insertedId = res.id; // get the id from the server response
            // use the id to set the filename of the selected file
            this.selectedFile = new File(
              [this.selectedFile],
              `${insertedId}.${this.selectedFile.name.split('.').pop()}`,
              { type: this.selectedFile.type }
            );
          },
          (err) => {
            console.error(err);
            this.errmsg = 'Error uploading file';
          }
        );
      } else if (this.birthdayRadioChecked) {
        this.service.BirthdayformData(formData).subscribe(
          (res) => {
            console.log(res);
            this.newsForm.reset();
            this.successmsg = res.message;
            const insertedId = res.id; // get the id from the server response
            // use the id to set the filename of the selected file
            this.selectedFile = new File(
              [this.selectedFile],
              `${insertedId}.${this.selectedFile.name.split('.').pop()}`,
              { type: this.selectedFile.type }
            );
          },
          (err) => {
            console.error(err);
            this.errmsg = 'Error uploading file';
          }
        );
      } else if (this.anniversaryRadioChecked) {
        this.service.AnniversaryformData(formData).subscribe(
          (res) => {
            console.log(res);
            this.newsForm.reset();
            this.successmsg = res.message;
            const insertedId = res.id; // get the id from the server response
            // use the id to set the filename of the selected file
            this.selectedFile = new File(
              [this.selectedFile],
              `${insertedId}.${this.selectedFile.name.split('.').pop()}`,
              { type: this.selectedFile.type }
            );
          },
          (err) => {
            console.error(err);
            this.errmsg = 'Error uploading file';
          }
        );
      } else {
        this.errmsg = 'All fields are required';
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

**My api service file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiserviceService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/register"

  getAllData():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}`)
  }
  createData(data:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}`,data)
  }
  UpdateData(data:any,id:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.put(`${this.apiUrl}/${id}`,data)
  }
  deleteData(id:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.delete(`${this.apiUrl}/${id}`)
  }
  getSingleData(id:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/${id}`)
  }
  LoginData(data:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/login`,data)
  }
  NewsformData(data:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/newsform`,data)
  }
  Newsformget():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/newsform')
  }
  BirthdayformData(data:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/birthdayform`,data)
  }
  AnniversaryformData(data:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/anniversaryform`,data)
  }
  ObituaryformData(data:any):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/obituaryform`,data)
  }
}


**My Nodejs backend file**

const upload2 = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
// Set the destination folder for uploaded files
cb(null, 'uploads/birthdayimage/');
},

    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const id = req.body.id;
      const originalName = file.originalname;
      const extension = originalName.split('.').pop();
      const newName = id + '.' + extension; // use the id to construct the filename
      cb(null, newName);
    },
  }),
});
const fs1 = require('fs');


app.post('/birthdayform', upload2.single('path'), (req, res) => {
  const headline = req.body.headline;
    const news = req.body.news;
  const currentdate = req.body.currentdate;
  const expirydate = req.body.expirydate;
  const path = req.file ? req.file.path : '';

  // insert the form data into the database
  const sql = 'INSERT INTO birthdayform (headline, news, path, currentdate, expirydate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
  db.query(sql, [headline, news, path, currentdate, expirydate], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error inserting data into the database: ', err);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error inserting data into the database' });
    } else if (result.affectedRows === 0) {
      console.error('Error inserting data into the database: no rows affected');
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error inserting data into the database: no rows affected' });
    } else {
      console.log('Data inserted into the database');
      const id = result.insertId;
      const extension = path.split('.').pop();
      const filename = `${id}.${extension}`;
      const newPath = `${path.slice(0, -extension.length)}${filename}`;
      fs1.renameSync(path, newPath); // rename the file with the new filename

      // update the path of the image in the database
      const sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE birthdayform SET path = ? WHERE id = ?';
db.query(sqlUpdate, [`uploads/birthdayimage/${filename}`, id], (err, result) => {
if (err) {
  console.error('Error updating path in the database: ', err);
  res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error updating path in the database' });
} else {
  console.log('Path updated in the database');
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data inserted into the database', id, filename }); // send the id and filename back to the client
}
});

    }
  });
});



const upload3 = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
// Set the destination folder for uploaded files
cb(null, 'uploads/obituaryimage/');
},

    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const id = req.body.id;
      const originalName = file.originalname;
      const extension = originalName.split('.').pop();
      const newName = id + '.' + extension; // use the id to construct the filename
      cb(null, newName);
    },
  }),
});
const fs2 = require('fs');


app.post('/obituaryform', upload3.single('path'), (req, res) => {
  const headline = req.body.headline;
    const news = req.body.news;
  const currentdate = req.body.currentdate;
  const expirydate = req.body.expirydate;
  const path = req.file ? req.file.path : '';

  // insert the form data into the database
  const sql = 'INSERT INTO obituaryform (headline, news, path, currentdate, expirydate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
  db.query(sql, [headline, news, path, currentdate, expirydate], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error inserting data into the database: ', err);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error inserting data into the database' });
    } else if (result.affectedRows === 0) {
      console.error('Error inserting data into the database: no rows affected');
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error inserting data into the database: no rows affected' });
    } else {
      console.log('Data inserted into the database');
      const id = result.insertId;
      const extension = path.split('.').pop();
      const filename = `${id}.${extension}`;
      const newPath = `${path.slice(0, -extension.length)}${filename}`;
      fs2.renameSync(path, newPath); // rename the file with the new filename

      // update the path of the image in the database
      const sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE obituaryform SET path = ? WHERE id = ?';
db.query(sqlUpdate, [`uploads/obituaryimage/${filename}`, id], (err, result) => {
if (err) {
  console.error('Error updating path in the database: ', err);
  res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error updating path in the database' });
} else {
  console.log('Path updated in the database');
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data inserted into the database', id, filename }); // send the id and filename back to the client
}
});

    }
  });
});






const upload4 = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
// Set the destination folder for uploaded files
cb(null, 'uploads/anniversaryimage/');
},

    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const id = req.body.id;
      const originalName = file.originalname;
      const extension = originalName.split('.').pop();
      const newName = id + '.' + extension; // use the id to construct the filename
      cb(null, newName);
    },
  }),
});
const fs3 = require('fs');


app.post('/anniversaryform', upload4.single('path'), (req, res) => {
  const headline = req.body.headline;
    const news = req.body.news;
  const currentdate = req.body.currentdate;
  const expirydate = req.body.expirydate;
  const path = req.file ? req.file.path : '';

  // insert the form data into the database
  const sql = 'INSERT INTO anniversaryform (headline, news, path, currentdate, expirydate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
  db.query(sql, [headline, news, path, currentdate, expirydate], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error inserting data into the database: ', err);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error inserting data into the database' });
    } else if (result.affectedRows === 0) {
      console.error('Error inserting data into the database: no rows affected');
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error inserting data into the database: no rows affected' });
    } else {
      console.log('Data inserted into the database');
      const id = result.insertId;
      const extension = path.split('.').pop();
      const filename = `${id}.${extension}`;
      const newPath = `${path.slice(0, -extension.length)}${filename}`;
      fs3.renameSync(path, newPath); // rename the file with the new filename

      // update the path of the image in the database
      const sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE anniversaryform SET path = ? WHERE id = ?';
db.query(sqlUpdate, [`uploads/anniversaryimage/${filename}`, id], (err, result) => {
if (err) {
  console.error('Error updating path in the database: ', err);
  res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error updating path in the database' });
} else {
  console.log('Path updated in the database');
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data inserted into the database', id, filename }); // send the id and filename back to the client
}
});

    }
  });
});
```

Please help me and check where the error is.